# Any application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk causes it to degrade

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, netbeans, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am developing a Java Web App with the NetBeans IDE and AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have created an RDS and S3 instance, where my application can successfully interact with both. However, my application can only interact with both RDS and S3 when the application is run locally through WildFly.

Whenever I try and deploy the application to Elastic Beanstalk, the instance becomes degraded. I believe I have configured both RDS and S3 instances correctly, i.e. attaching the correct security groups.

For debugging purposes, I created a blank Java Web App through NetBeans (generic Hello, World! JSP) and when I deployed that application to Elastic Beanstalk, the instance also became degraded. Therefore, I have concluded that whenever I deploy ANY application to Elastic Beanstalk, the instance degrades.

Why is Elastic Beanstalk degrading? Especially with a simple Hello World! application?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do the Elastic Beanstalk logs say?  At a guess it's a network issue but I wouldn't know for sure without logs.  The console allows you to get logs if they are in a standard place.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In /var/log/nginx/error.log I got the error
[error] 30044#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx/", host: "xx.xxx.xx.xxx"

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you're deploying this since Wildfly is, unfortunately, not a supported configuration in Elastic Beanstalk.  However, if NGINX can't connect then the first thing is to understand why it can't connect to, likely, localhost:8080.  Do you use the Docker deployment?  If not, how are you deploying to Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: I am using NetBeans to deploy. To deploy to EB, I change the run-time server to an EB I added and simply run the project. Whenever I want to run locally and not deploy to EB, I change the run-time server to WildFly. I've been capable of deploying to EB for a few weeks now, but the last week it's been acting up.